# C# from numeric to double

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

we have a value in our database that is numeric we take through the database and then we want to insert it to another value but we want it to be converted to *DOUBLE* from *Numeric*

So any ideas how can we convert our Numeric variable to double ?

**edit**

Database = Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient) (.mdf)

```
double point = 0;


cn.Open();
point = Convert.ToDouble("select bounty from provider where sirname = '" + globals2.stringena + "' ");
cn.close();
```

bounty = Numeric(18,2)

so want to pass this value to my point variable.

The error i get is

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: What database? SQL, Access, etc?

Comment: Could you please add code snippet that you use for getting you numeric value from database.

Comment: ok i put code so you can see what i wanna do.

Comment: So you already know how to convert a C# `decimal` value to `double`: you can use `Convert.ToDouble`. Is your question really "How do I retrieve a value from the database?"?

Comment: Check the error i get from the debugg

Comment: Convert.ToDouble will only convert strings which have only digits and/or a period.  If the value you want to convert is already a number try casting it directly, put (Double) in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
string query = "select bounty from provider where sirname = @name";
double numericToDouble = 0;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(YourDB.ConnectionString)
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@name,"nameYouNeed");
        try{
          con.Open();
          SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          if (reader.Read())
             numericToDouble = Convert.ToDouble32(reader[0].ToString());
          con.Close();
        }
        catch(SqlError someError)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(someError.Message);
        }
    } 
}
```

**Note:**  the @name is a parameter that we need to pass to the query at runtime.
so I created an sql command that uses the query and connect to the DB. 
when the new command is create it passes the value of @name, if you see the line "cmd.parameters...." 
after that it reads from the DB, and check if it succeeded to read something, if so it convert the value to string and then to double. 
**I assumed that the numeric field is the first column in your table. 
If it's not you can change the code FROM:**

```
numericToDouble = Convert.ToDouble32(reader[0].ToString());
```

**TO:**

```
numericToDouble = Convert.ToDouble32(reader["NameOfTheNumericField"].ToString());
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: I dont think a method exist like Convert.ToDouble32.

Comment: you can actually do     reader.GetSqlDecimal(0).ToDouble()     to avoid error-prone string parsing.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayes1wa5.aspx
it exists in .NET 4.5

Comment: @Elior the link you provided above also doesn't show any method named Convert.ToDouble32. Method name is Convert.ToDouble in which one of the overload takes parameter System.Int32.